# Rules with VBO in views

Tags: 7, rules, views

I have a view (using the table display format) that is showing all the node of a content type (A), and that content type has a reference to nodes of another content type (B). I added a VBO field to that view.

How can I create a content type B node for each node of the selected node (content type A) by setting the values just one time in the content type B create form?
(I need to create B nodes with the same field values for each node of A.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get started is to watch the video series [Learn the Rules Framework](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-the-rules-framework).  It will demonstrate how to create the node and populate any data fields according to the content in your type A node.